# Как распределить числа из массива js

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Задача такая:

```
var streak = {
  min: '',
  max: '',
  length: '',
  series: []
}

var allStreaks = []
```

У меня есть массив чисел:

```
var arr = [19, 20, 21, 22, 17, 18, 19, 7, 8, 9]
```

Мне нужно распределить их по массивам чтобы в нем были эти числа в порядке возрастания, и записать все это в таком формате:

```
[{
  min: 19,
  max: 22,
  length: 4,
  series: [19, 20, 21, 22]
}, {
  min: 17,
  max: 19,
  length: 3,
  series: [17, 18, 19]
}, {
  min: 7,
  max: 9,
  length: 3,
  series: [7, 8, 9]
}]
```

В исходном массиве числа идут в том порядке в котором они мне нужны будут (как будто если бы эти числа шли по датам - одно число - один день) Мне нужно отловить сколько "дней" эти числа увеличивались, с какого числа началось и на каком остановилось и потом все сначала. Первые 4 числа массива arr (19 20 21 22) должны создать объект в котором будет записано минимальное число (19), максимальное число (22), сколько всего чисел было записано (4) и собственно сам массив этих чисел [19, 20, 21, 22]. Точно так же со вторым возрастающим стриком с 17 до 19 итд
        Числа в исходном массиве абсолютно рандомные и нужно отследить эту череду увеличений и как только встречается число меньше предыдущего начать новый массив

На данный момент делаю так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
  if (arr[i] < arr[i+1]) {
    streak.series.push(arr[i])
  } else {
    streak.series.push(arr[i]) //Сохранит последний элемент первого стрика
    break;
  } 
}
```

Так я успешно получаю первый стрик, однако если мне надо продолжить, то возникают трудности:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
  if (arr[i] < arr[i+1]) {
    streak.series.push(arr[i])
  } else if ((arr[i] > arr[i-1]) && (arr[i] > arr[i+1])) {
    streak.series.push(arr[i]) // Это ловит и записывает последний элемент первого стрика, получается steak.series = [19,20,21,22]
    // но он на этом не останавливается и продолжает записывать все числа исходного массива
    // так как они потом подходят под первый if (arr[i] < arr[i+1])
    // и в результате у меня просто переписывается весь исходный массив
  } else {continue;} 
}
```

Comment: как обрабатывать равенство элементов?

Comment: Как Вы их вообще распределяете?

Comment: Сначала пытался распределить простым условием if (arr[i] < arr[i+1]) {allStreaks.push(arr[i])}, но тогда я не могу отловить последний элемент, если делаю проверку в стиле else if ( ( arr[i] > arr[i-1] ) && ( arr[i] > arr[i+1] )  ) {allStreaks.push(arr[i])} тогда он в один аррей вставляет все числа сразу

Comment: Вам намекают на то, что непонятна логика распределения. почему из одного массива получается аж целых три..... Я бы вот лично понял, если у вас идет сортировка в каждом десятке (0-9, 10-19, 20-29 и т.д.)...но у вас число 19 и в первом объекте итогого массива и во втором

Comment: В исходном массиве числа идут в том порядке в котором они мне нужны будут (как будто если бы эти числа шли по датам - одно число - один день) Мне нужно отловить сколько "дней" эти числа увеличивались, с какого числа началось и на каком остановилось и потом все сначала. Первые 4 числа массива arr (19 20 21 22) должны создать объект в котором будет записано минимальное число (19), максимальное число (22), сколько всего чисел было записано (4) и собственно сам массив этих чисел [19, 20, 21, 22]. Точно так же со вторым возрастающим стриком с 17 до 19 итд

Comment: Числа в исходном массиве абсолютно рандомные и нужно отследить эту череду увеличений и как только встречается число меньше предыдущего начать новый массив

Comment: @Ivan добавьте весь ваш код в вопрос. со всеми циклами, ифами и прочим. чтоб видно было что у вас есть

Comment: @Ivan такой результат нужен был?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    var arr = [19, 20, 21, 22, 17, 18, 19, 7, 8, 9]
    var resArr = [];
    var min = max = length = 0;
    var tempArr = [];
    var prev = 0;
    
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
      if(prev > item && prev){
         resArr.push({'min':min,'max':max,'length':length, 'series':tempArr});
         min = 0;
         max = 0;
         tempArr = [];
         length = 0;
      }
      if(item > max) max = item;
      if(item < min || min == 0) min = item;
      length++;
      tempArr.push(item);
      prev = item;
    });
    resArr.push({'min':min,'max':max,'length':length, 'series':tempArr});
    console.log(resArr);
```

Comment: Да!! Спасибо большое, долго ломал голову

Comment: @Ivan имхо много лишних проверок  и установок if то, тогда так, а если так, то так, когда достаточно одной...и временных переменных с массивами тоже чет перебор.....но это мое мнение

Comment: @АлексейШиманский т.е. вы хотите сказать что 3 условия хуже  3 циклов?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var allStreaks = [];
var arr = [19, 20, 21, 22, 17, 18, 19, 7, 8, 9];
var prevMaxPos = 0;

doWork();
console.log(allStreaks);

// функции работы и заноса в итоговый массив
function doWork() {
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
      allStreaks.push(setStreak(arr.slice(prevMaxPos, i)));
      prevMaxPos = i;
    }
  }

  if (arr.slice(prevMaxPos).length > 0)
    allStreaks.push(setStreak(arr.slice(prevMaxPos)));
}

function setStreak(arr) {
  return streak = {
    min: arr[0],
    max: arr[arr.length - 1],
    length: arr.length,
    series: arr
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Большое! Очень помогло. Тоже очень хороший вариант! Даже попроще, у меня в исходном массиве может быть больше 500-1000 объектов. Так тоже пытался сделать, начал ругаться на Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 1):

решение в стиле минимализм ...

```js
var arr = [19, 20, 21, 22, 17, 18, 19, 7, 8, 9];

function go(d) {
  var a;
  return d.reduce(function(c, b) {
    a && b == a.max + 1 ? (a.max = b, a.length++, a.series.push(b)) :
      (a = {
        min: b,
        max: b,
        length: 1,
        series: [b]
      }, c.push(a));
    return c
  }, [])
};
console.log(go(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

ещё одно минималистическое, но читаемое решение

```js
var arr = [19, 20, 21, 22, 17, 18, 19, 7, 8, 9],        
    distribute = function(arr) {
      var out = [], series = [], i = 1;
      while (i < arr.length + 1) {
        series.push( arr[i-1] );
        if (! (arr[i-1] < arr[i++])) {
            out.push({
             min:     series[0],
             max:     series[series.length-1],
             length:  series.length,
             series:  series.slice()
           });
           series = [];
         }
      }
      return out;
    }


console.log( distribute(arr) );
```